# How can get the END CALL message by Bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, call

We build a VoIP APP, but it doesn't support CallKit yet.

The iPhone connects another device (for example : a device in a car likes carplay ) by bluetooth(HFP/A2DP) first.

The user opens this App and join the VoIP, he can talk with other people using the device, the iPhone connects the device by bluetooth, it works well.

There are 2 UIs in this device likes the carplay, and the user can switch between 2 UIs.

- **The first UI :** there are play/stop/next/previous button in the UI, we click this button, the App can receive the message by the
  MPRemoteCommandCenter.
- **The second UI :** there is a END CALL button in it, when I click the button, we can't any message.

The iOS system log shows:

```
bluetoothd   Received call hangup event (AT+CHUP) from device <private>

bluetoothd   Found ongoing virtual call - Acking device and notifying upper layers.
```

So I think the device has send a message to iPhone system by bluetooth, but the App can't receive this message from iPhone system. I try using the MPRemoteCommandCenter/CTCallCenter, but failed.

How can get this message?

Comment: Adopt callkit and then your app will integrate with the system call interface.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but our App can't support CallKit for some reasons.We had build a test App, the test App can receive the END CALL msg by BT. Thanks again.